# "Ценный" и "бесценный"

Tags: словообразование, приставка

Интересно, что слово ***бесценный*** образовано от слова ***ценный*** с помощью отрицательной приставки *бес-* (*без-*), но в итоге получается не антоним, а слово, выражающее то же самое, только ещё ярче.

*Есть ли ещё подобные слова и есть ли название для таких пар?*

Comment: с ценой интересно получилось: её отсутствие - признак что вещь не продаётся (очень дорога владельцу) или не покупается (никому даром не нужна)? в случае "бесценный" - первое. в случае "обесценивать" - второе. поди ж ты пойми этот глубинный народ 

Answer (score 1):

Таких пар сравнительно мало для обобщающего названия (хотя всякое может быть). Из того, что приходит на ум:

> **условно** + прилагательное <-> **безусловно** + прилагательное (напр. *условно годный* - *безусловно годный*)
>
> **прецедентный** (настолько значимый, что на него ссылаются как на более ранний случай)
>   <-> **беспрецедентный** (из ряда вон выходящий, которому ранее не было сопоставимых)

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, в том числе и за другие примеры!

Comment: Нешто это синонимы? Автор ведь просил синонимы.

Comment: @Niemand: любые не антонимы тоже интересны.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Так это именно антонимы.